# Adding a filter for MIN function using WHERE condition Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I need have below query which returns the MIN(date) from the table, however I want to add a where condition to the query to select the dates only between 2021-01-01 and 2021-04-01.

```
SELECT MIN(file.date_received) as date
FROM `file`
JOIN `ref` ON `ref`.`r_id` = `file`.`r_id`
JOIN `screening` ON `screening`.`screen_id` = `ref`.`r_id`
WHERE `ref`.`out` = 4
GROUP BY `file`.`r_id
```

When I add the below where condition to the query, I get the error below

> Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

```
SELECT MIN(file.date_received) as date
FROM `file`
JOIN `ref` ON `ref`.`r_id` = `file`.`r_id`
JOIN `screening` ON `screening`.`screen_id` = `ref`.`r_id`
WHERE `ref`.`out` = 4
AND  MIN(file.date_received)  > '2021-01-01' AND  MIN(file.date_received)  < '2021-04-01'
GROUP BY `file`.`r_id
```

Comment: Use the `HAVING` clause instead of `WHERE`.

Comment: you could use between as well. and guess there is no need of using MIN in where clause.

Comment: `where` is evaluated before `group by`. That's why DBMS doesn't yet know how to calculate `min(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for aggregated  result you need HAVING

```
SELECT MIN(file.date_received) as date
FROM `file`
JOIN `ref` ON `ref`.`r_id` = `file`.`r_id`
JOIN `screening` ON `screening`.`screen_id` = `ref`.`r_id`
WHERE `ref`.`out` = 4
GROUP BY `file`.`r_id
HAVING MIN(file.date_received)  > '2021-01-01'  AND MIN(file.date_received)  < '2021-04-01
```

Comment: sorry there was group by which was missed in the originial post

Comment: @mahen3d  answer  updated ..

Answer (score 1):

It is unnecessary to use `MIN` in `WHERE`-clause since you are filtering your results in your `SELECT`-statement.

To range a date you could use `BETWEEN` instead.

```
SELECT MIN(file.date_received) as date
FROM `file`
JOIN `ref` ON `ref`.`r_id` = `file`.`r_id`
JOIN `screening` ON `screening`.`screen_id` = `ref`.`r_id`
WHERE `ref`.`out` = 4
AND  file.date_received BETWEEN CAST('2021-01-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2021-04-01' AS DATE) 
GROUP BY `file`.`r_id
```